# Recover data from before import

Tags: mysql, database, import, xampp

I have imported by mistake old database file on my new database file in xampp server. After that all my new tables are replaced by old ones and I didn't do the backup of the new database.

Is there any possibles to recover the database in this situation? If yes please let me know. Thank you

Comment: Have you enabled bin log files?

Comment: where do I know whether I enabled bin log file or not

Comment: check it is ON `show variables like 'log_bin'`